# Laravel 5.4 internal server error while loading views from sub directory

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, internal-server-error, laravel-blade

I am new to laravel and just installed 5.4 version using composer.I created a new folder inside resources/views/**pages** and put a file named index.blade.php inside it. I am getting 500 internal server error while loading it inside the controller. I am unable to figure the problem out. the route I am using is:

Route::get('/','HomeController@index');

If I put index.blade.php inside views directory and use **view('index');**
there is no problem loading this. here is the directory strecture that I am using

[image]

```html
HomeController.php

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){

     return view('pages.home.index');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

pages.home.index means that it would try to read a file called index.blade.php from the resources/pages/home directory.

So to solve your problem create the "home" directory inside of "pages" and move the index.blade.php there.

The other example works properly because view('index'); reads the file called index.blade.php from the resources directory.

Comment: it's still showing : localhost is currently unable to handle this request. (500 error )